# form action not working to redirect in django v2

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

The form action is not redirecting from home.html to password.html in Django 2 even I recheck everything including URL pattern
Below I am sharing the basic code. My apologies if it's a basic question as I am very new to Django that's why I may not able to detect the issue.

**urls.py code**

```
from django.urls import path
from generator import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('password/', views.password),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'generator/home.html')

def password(request):
    return render(request, 'generator/password.html')
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Password Generator</h1>

<form action="password" method="get">
    <select name="length">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Generate Password">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

**password.py**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Password</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Password page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error Log**
[image]

**File Structure**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all give names in urls.py so you can access it by name.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name="index"),
    path('password/', views.password,name="password"),
]
```

in `home.html` remove `form`'s action

in `views.py`

```
from django.urls import reverse

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #you can access input items of form by `request.POST.get('attribute_name')`
        # your logic
        return redirect(reverse('password')
    else:
        return render(request, 'generator/home.html')
```

if still not getting error then please share whole code and what you want to achieve